# jQuery: on focus show delbutton

Tags: jquery

I have this right now:

```
        <td id="delPMicon" style="padding-right:4px;padding:4px;">
                            ...Removebutton....
                        </td>
```

This is a delete button inside every `<tr>` (rows the database spitted out, used while() in PHP).

All the `<tr>` has a id #pm at the moment.

I would like to when you focus with your mouse/mark over with your mouse, over the `<tr>` the #delPMicon should appear, and then go away onblur.

I have tried this:

```
added css property to #delPMicon: display:none; and then:
$('#pm').focus(function() {
  $('#delPMicon').show();
});
```

This doesn't work, don't know what i did wrong.

I also know that id can only be used once, so the #pm focus will only work on one `<tr>` (if it worked properly), how can i solve this? I cant use class to the `<tr>`, as im using that for another function. What i can do (that i can think of) is adding the id of the row to the #pm, so it would be: #pm22, but then how can i say to the JS what id it should look after?

Or maybe i can add this .focus function to each tr in the while loop in order to get the ids, so i could do:

```
$('#pm<?php echo $id; ?>').focus(function() {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.pm').hover(function() {
    function() { $(this).find('.delPMicon').show(); },
    function() { $(this).find('.delPMicon').hide(); }
});
```

You can use the same class for all elements that currently have the same id.  Then use the 'this' reference to attach an event handler to each one individually.

Comment: Shouldn't the parameters for hover be: hover(function(){...}, function(){...}); The first parameter is what happens when your mouse enters the area over the selector, and the second parameter is what happens when your mouse leaves the area over the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS

```
tr > td#delPMIcon { display: none; }
tr:hover > td#delPMIcon { display: table-cell; }
```